# Can anyone identify this chart name

Tags: charts

Actually, I found one chart but don't know the named, so can anyone give me the name for the following chart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a box plot with each box's min = start value in the month and max = end value in the month.

Comment: I know the logic behind it, i want name of this chart